Using URL for state, nextJS
Hey I have a component which handles log in and sign up forms
I have steps for sign up, step 1 and step two
I want to have the state of the steps to be visible in the URL so I can use them, but not in the signup page.
so, then I can redirect to step two if needed, from sign in page
now the state of the steps is handled via useState so I cannot redirect to lets say "signup?step=2"
how do I handle that signup catches all routes? right now its under

app/(auth)/signup/page.tsx

tried to change it to

app/(auth)/signup/[...slug]/page.tsx

and adding in the code
if (isRegisterPage) router.push(`signup?step=${step}`}

but getting an error (page doesnt exist), and it doesn't work
here is the code:
"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";

import SignInForm from "../forms/signInForm";
import SignUpFormStepOne from "../forms/signnUpFormStepOne";
import { hebrewTranslations } from "@/shared/lib/constants";
import SignUpFormStepTwo from "../forms/signUpFormStepTwo";

const SignInUp = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const isPersonalDetails = step === 2;
  const isRegisterPage = pathname === "/signup";
  const isLoginPage = pathname === "/signin";
  const linkButton = isLoginPage ? "/signup" : isRegisterPage ? "/signin" : "";

  return (
    <section className="flex min-h-screen w-full flex-1 flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-100 px-20 py-2 text-center">
      <div className="fixed z-[1] mt-80 h-8 w-full skew-y-[-30deg] transform bg-green2 md:skew-y-[-6deg]"></div>
      <div className="fixed z-[2] flex w-2/3 max-w-4xl rounded-2xl bg-slate-100 shadow-2xl">
        <section
          className={`bg-neutral-100 p-8 md:w-[${
            isPersonalDetails ? "100%" : "70%"
          }]`}
        >
          <div className="select-none text-right font-bold text-green2">
            .Coach
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${isRegisterPage ? "pb-10 pt-4" : ""} ${
              isLoginPage && "py-10"
            }`}
          >
            <h2 className="mb-2 select-none text-3xl font-bold text-green2">
              {isRegisterPage &&
                step === 1 &&
                hebrewTranslations["register_site"]}
              {isRegisterPage &&
                step === 2 &&
                hebrewTranslations["personalDetails"]}
              {isLoginPage && hebrewTranslations["sign_in_account"]}
            </h2>
            <div className="hr mb-2 hidden w-28 border-2 border-green2 md:inline-block"></div>
            {isRegisterPage && step === 1 && (
              <SignUpFormStepOne setStep={setStep} setEmail={setEmail} />
            )}
            {isRegisterPage && step === 2 && (
              <SignUpFormStepTwo email={email} />
            )}
            {isLoginPage && <SignInForm />}
          </div>
        </section>
        {step !== 2 && (
          <section className="hidden w-[30%] rounded-l-2xl bg-green2 py-48 text-slate-100 md:block lg:px-12 ">
            <h2 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold lg:text-3xl">
              {hebrewTranslations["hello_friend"]}
            </h2>
            <div className="mb-4 inline-block w-10 border-2 border-white"></div>
            <p className="mb-4">
              {isLoginPage && hebrewTranslations["account_question"]}
              {isRegisterPage && hebrewTranslations["register_question"]}
            </p>
            <Link
              href={linkButton}
              className="inline-block rounded-full border-2 border-slate-200 py-2 font-semibold transition duration-500 hover:border-green1 hover:bg-slate-200 hover:text-green2 md:px-6 lg:px-8 xl:px-12"
            >
              {isLoginPage && hebrewTranslations["register"]}
              {isRegisterPage && hebrewTranslations["login"]}
            </Link>
          </section>
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SignInUp;

